# In Gremlin, how can one query vertices where one property value is greater than another property value?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm sure this is straightforward, but I'm not sure how to do it. I have vertices, with a certain label, which have two integer properties. Let's call them integer1 and integer2. I simply want to query for all vertices where integer2 is greater than integer1.

I have tried the following:

```
g.V().hasLabel("myLabel").has("integer2", P.gt(values("integer1"))).toList();
```

but this results in an exception - understandably, as the the "values" method call results in a traversal step where as the predicate expects a number.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:52)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Compare$3.test(Compare.java:92)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.P.test(P.java:72)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.HasContainer.testValue(HasContainer.java:118)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.HasContainer.test(HasContainer.java:94)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.HasContainer.testAll(HasContainer.java:180)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.TinkerGraphStep.iteratorList(TinkerGraphStep.java:116)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.TinkerGraphStep.vertices(TinkerGraphStep.java:88)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.TinkerGraphStep.lambda$new$0(TinkerGraphStep.java:59)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.TinkerGraphStep$$Lambda$23/1123629720.get(Unknown Source)
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it would be with a `where()` clause. First, to demonstrate I modified the "modern" graph to include a "k" property with an integer value:

```
g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
g.V().hasLabel('person').property('k',30)
```

and then:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').as('a').
......1>   where('a', gt('a')).by('age').by('k').
......2>   valueMap('age','k')
==>[k:[30],age:[32]]
==>[k:[30],age:[35]]
```

Comment: As usual, Stephen, I'm impressed with your knowledge and responsiveness. This worked. I need to better understand the underlying traversal mechanisms to gain a more intuitive understanding of the syntax. Aside from the standard Tinkerpop documentation, do you recommend anything else to read?

Comment: well, i'd always recommend: http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html and folks often miss the recipes: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/ but also note that a new book on graphs/Gremlin is in early release right now with manning: https://www.manning.com/books/graph-databases-in-action